# SQL change field Collation in a select

Tags: sql-server

i'm trying to do the following select:

```
select * from urlpath where substring(urlpathpath, 3, len(urlpathpath))
not in (select accessuserpassword from accessuser where accessuserparentid = 257)
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between 
"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI" and 
"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

Does anyone know how i can cast as a collation, or something that permits me to match this condition?

Thanx

Comment: +1 This happened to me more than once, and God knows I was happy to learn about the `COLLATE` instruction! =)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add `COLLATE CollationName` after the column name for the column you want to "re-collate". (Note: the collation name is literal, not quoted)

Comment: @Luceroe: Precisely! I couldn't agree more! =)

Comment: @André: Well, all credits go to Lucero! =) Thanks anyway for having including me in your thanks. =)

Comment: 13 years on and somehow I still needed this to fix up a query. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 7):

You can even do the collate on the query to create a new table with that query, for example:

```
SELECT 
    * 
INTO 
    #TempTable  
FROM 
    View_total
WHERE 
        YEAR(ValidFrom) <= 2007 
    AND YEAR(ValidTo)>= 2007 
    AND Id_Product = '001' 
    AND ProductLine COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (SELECT Product FROM #TempAUX)
```

COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT causes the COLLATE clause inherits the collation of the current database, eliminating the difference between the two