# How to set collation of a column with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

Originally, I created my SQL Server database on a local computer. I set its collation to `Latin1_General_CI_AI` and everything worked well. When I moved the finished work to the web hosting SQL Server, I encountered problem: they use a different database collation. So what can I do now?

To be more specific, I need `Latin1_General_CI_AI`, but they have `Czech_CI_AS`. These two differ significantly when comparing strings in Czech language (surprisingly I need latin1 general, not Czech, to get correct results.)

When I tried to change collation of my database, the server complained that I don't have user permission to do that. I tried to contact support desk, but no luck. Can I help myself?

I know that possibly each single table column can have its own collation, so maybe I should set up all my string columns to `Latin1_CI_AI`. But I don't know how to do this. I have only SQL access to the database (unfortunately no SQL Server Management Studio).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL change field Collation in a select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484066/sql-change-field-collation-in-a-select)

Comment: @questionto42 No

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To change the database's collation

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDataBase COLLATE [NewCollation]
```

To change the collation of a column

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN Column1 [TYPE] COLLATE [NewCollation]
```

But there are a number of limitations on when you can do this, very notably that this is denied if the column is used in any index.
You can do more in SSMS in some cases.
The syntax docs list the restrictions:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Maybe these commands are correct, but they don't work for me. The first one says that I have no permission to do that, the second says that there is a dependant object CK_something on that column, so the collation cannot be changed. (It doesn't make sense to me - I don't understand what is that dependant object, and why it blocks the collation.)

Comment: Finally, what worked for me: I created "CREATE TABLE" script in SQL Management Studio, then opened it in notepad and manually added `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI' to each `NVARCHAR' column definition. Then I executed this script in a new empty database on the webhosting server.

Comment: I think the CK_something might be a Clustered Key, any kind of key is considered an object in the database, if you want to delete or change a column that has a key on it you have to remove the key first and add it back if needed (In SQLMS you can create the scritps to Create and Delete the key).

Comment: it seems correct that we cannot use t-sql ALTER TABLE to change the collation if the column participates in any indexes.  It can be done in SSMS -  perhaps it rebuilds the indexes silently. (I believe there is a setting to allow that)

Answer (score 5):

I tried this code and it's working for me :

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable 
ALTER COLUMN CharCol VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8
```

reference :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This is exactly the same as the accepted answer from 2012. Or what is your point?