# SQLServer 2005 does not do the right thing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a problem when trying with `Like` statement like this:

First I have the data sheet:

[image: Image Data]

When I execute the Sql command it does not do what I want.

My syntax:

```
select * from tbUsers where nUserID like N'%p%';
```

It does not show any results. Although I know that 'Finds any values ​​that have' p 'in any position'

result picture:

[image: result]

my code to create table:

```
Create table tbUsers(
iIDUser int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
nUserID nvarchar(50) null,
nPassWord nvarchar(50) null,
dDate datetime null,
nName nvarchar(50) null
)
INSERT INTO tbUsers(nUserID,nPassword,nName) VALUES('phuc','123456', 'Phuc Nguyen')
INSERT INTO tbUsers(nUserID,nPassword) VALUES('ngocanh','123456')
INSERT INTO tbUsers(nUserID,nPassword) VALUES('long','123456')
INSERT INTO tbUsers(nUserID,nPassword) VALUES('long%ngocanh','123456')
INSERT INTO tbUsers(nUserID,nPassword) VALUES('phuc nguyen','123456')
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: It would be better to post sample data as text instead of images. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Maybe that `p` in your picture isn't really a `p`. Impossible for us to tell with an image though.

Comment: Try removing the N before the string with the wild card

Comment: @Juan not work for me.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks i update my code to create table. Im newbie.

Comment: Can you check the encoding of the database

Comment: Are you running your SELECT against the correct database?

Comment: @Juan i right click to my database > properties > in collation i found 'Vietnamese_CI_AS'

Comment: @TDP I checked and it is not a problem.

Comment: I think this is the reason of your problem, re create the database with encoding SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and try again

Comment: @Juan they don't need to drop the database and start over. There are very likely some good reason they are using that collation.

Comment: Well he can stay with the current one, and create a new one just for testing, then he can decide what to do next.

Comment: Excellent job posting details. Makes this super easy to help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Vietnamese collation you are not getting back the rows. You can specify the collation in your query quite easily though and it will return the rows you are looking for.

```
select * 
from tbUsers 
where nUserID collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS like N'%p%';
```

Comment: LOL. You aren't the only person who might realize that the collation is the issue. And this actually solves the problem as opposed to your suggestion of recreating the database. Feel free to post your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hi your problem can be your collation if you need the Vietnamese collation for any reason you can alter your query to use the collation in your query like this one:

```
select * 
from tbUsers 
where nUserID collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS like N'%p%';
```

If not my recommendation is to re-create the database using the collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS since this query will be slow.

Also take in consideration if you have an index in the user column using double %% this will not let your index to be used. If you use only one % the index will be activated. Take a look of the execution plan to review this.

If want to stay with the Vietnamese collation maybe change the collation to the columns you need for this type of functionality. This will help you with the performance.

To change the collation of a column use

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN Column1 [TYPE] COLLATE [NewCollation]
```

You can take a look to this question for more details

[How to set collation of a column with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205881/how-to-set-collation-of-a-column-with-sql)

Comment: Good answer and bonus points for pointing out that inline collation and leading wildcards can greatly hinder performance. +1