# Ignore Case Sensitivity While Querying Data

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2017

I have a database in Azure SQL Server with collation as '**SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS**' and in that i have table that has two columns

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.TABLE1(
[ROWID] [numeric](16, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CODE] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
```

)

Now below query works fine in Azure SQL ignoring the case sensitivity of column names

```
SELECT rowID, coDE FROM DBO.TABLE1
SELECT rowid, code FROM DBO.TABLE1
```

But when i create the database on a Sql Server inside Azure VM (IaaS solution) with same collation setting: 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS' then above queries are not working at all its throwing below error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'rowid'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'code'.
```

How do i suppress this case sensitivity of column name while querying tables in Sql server on Azure VM.

Please advice.

Comment: *"How do i suppress this case sensitivity of column name while querying tables in Sql server on Azure VM."* Change the collation of the database to be non-case sensitive collation.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database always uses [contained database collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-database-collations?view=sql-server-ver15), which allows you to have a case-sensitive database without having a case-sensitive catalog (yuck).

> In a contained database, the catalog collation
>   Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_WS_KS_SC. This collation is the same for all
>   contained databases on all instances of SQL Server and cannot be
>   changed.

In SQL Sever on an Azure VM you can get the same behavior by using a [contained database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-ver15).  Your database collation (and the default collation of all your table columns) can be `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`, but your table names, column names, proc names, etc will use the case-insensitive `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_WS_KS_SC`.

Answer (score -1):

`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` is case-sensitive, compare to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` which is case-insensitive. It's better to change your DB collation.

Comment: Is it better to change your db collation? What if you need CS?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Then I expect the OP would refer to [How to set collation of a column with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12205881/1115360)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I agree (with that solution).

Comment: There are 20 thousand tables in my database and its impossible to change collation for each tables. Is it not possible to replicate same Azure Sql Server behaviour With CS in on prem sql server in Azure VM. Please help.

Comment: @user1941025 so in that case change your query, (and why downvoting?)

Comment: @user1941025 It appears that you forgot to include that information in the question.