# How to use EXCEPT clause in multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query with an except clause. Underneath the except, my 2nd query is coming from a different database than the one that the first query is using.

It looks something like this

```
SELECT field1 as a
FROM table 1
EXCEPT
USE differentdb
SELECT field2 as a
FROM table 2
```

I have also tried this

```
SELECT field1 as a
FROM table 1
EXCEPT
USE differentdb
SELECT field2 as a
FROM differentdb.dbo.table2
```

I realize that this is not allowed in SQL because I get the following error:

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 1 Cannot resolve the collation
>   conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and
>   "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

I am wondering if there is another way to write this query and accomplish a cross-db EXCEPT clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of collation conflict for SQL Server view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544392/how-to-get-rid-of-collation-conflict-for-sql-server-view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the collation of column on the fly like:

```
SELECT field1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as a
FROM table 1
EXCEPT
SELECT differentdb.SchemaName.field2 as a
FROM table 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Us can use [collate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) clause to convert collation from other database.

```
SELECT field2 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as a
FROM table 2
```

Here you should use correct collation - because it is not enough information what is collation of your first and second databases.

Or you can simply use

```
SELECT field2 collate database_default as a
FROM table 2
```

This will cause the `collate` clause to inherit the collation of the current database