# SQL query conflict between "Thai_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, collation

Hi may i know what wrong this this query

```
SELECT [no]
--  into #mytemp
  FROM [pcb_comp]
  where no in (SELECT [no] FROM [Data_Query].[dbo].[query]
  where [no] NOT IN (select no from [IPTS2].[dbo].[abc]))
  and location = 'PCB'
  order by no
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: the purpose for this query is search from pcb_comp, match with query table, if not found serach from abc table

Comment: You can force collations on certain columns and manually resolve the conflict, q.v. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544392/how-to-get-rid-of-collation-conflict-in-a-sql-server-query

Comment: if i write same like above will get the error for "Thai_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

Comment: You should post your schema and tell us what the collations are for each table/column in your query.

Comment: The problem is that columns are being compared but they are in different collations and so they can't be compared. For example there are characters in thai that have no similar latin character and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is problem in collation conflict with Location column than use below:

```
SELECT [no]
--  into #mytemp
  FROM [pcb_comp]
  where no in (SELECT [no] FROM [Data_Query].[dbo].[query]
  where [no] NOT IN (select no from [IPTS2].[dbo].[abc]))
  and location COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = 'PCB' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
  order by no
```

same applies to your 'in' filter if above does not work.