# If statement to check SQL collation then run query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I just had some great help on a question I asked which was answered a moment ago ([Query over two databases has error due to collation mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186025/query-over-two-databases-has-error-due-to-collation-mismatch)) to overcome a collation error for a MSSQL query I'm working with.

Is there a way for the query to check the DB collation first?

Hypothetical example (I have no idea on the syntax):

```
CASE 
  WHEN DATABASEPROPERTYEX('PracticeEvolve_c1.dbo, 'Collation') SQLCollation = 'COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' 
  THEN 
    CASE 
      WHEN [dd_entity_d2].[type] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ='Individual' 
      THEN etClient.FirstName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
      ELSE [dd_entity_d4].[firstname] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
    END AS FirstName,
  ELSE 
    CASE 
      WHEN [dd_entity_d2].[type] ='Individual' 
      THEN etClient.FirstName 
      ELSE [dd_entity_d4].[firstname] 
    END AS FirstName 
END,

CASE 
  WHEN DATABASEPROPERTYEX('PracticeEvolve_c1.dbo, 'Collation') SQLCollation = 'COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' 
  THEN 
    CASE 
      WHEN [dd_entity_d2].[type] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ='Individual' 
      THEN etClient.LastName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
      ELSE [dd_entity_d4].[lastname] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
    END AS LastName,
  ELSE 
    CASE 
      WHEN [dd_entity_d2].[type] ='Individual' 
      THEN etClient.LastName 
      ELSE [dd_entity_d4].[lastname] 
    END AS LastName 
END,
```

This way I won't have to use a different query if I come across one of the servers at our sites that uses different collation on the PracticeEvolve_c1 database to the other servers.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use

`COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` instead of `COLLATE <specific_collation_name>`

and you wouldn't need to check for which collation is being used.

Best practise, however, is to use the same collation across all databases unless needs must otherwise