# SQL Server : error joining two tables from two different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am using SSMS, I am trying to join two tables from two different databases, both in the same server.

The two tables have a common `id` column.

My query is :

```
select * 
from db1.dbo.EPH e 
join db2.dbo.SALARIE s on e.id = s.id
```

I'm getting this error:

> Unable to resolve collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "French_CI_AS" in operation equal to.

Comment: You have inconsistent table definitions. You have to decide which collation to use when comparing the columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix a collation conflict in a SQL Server query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544392/how-to-fix-a-collation-conflict-in-a-sql-server-query)

Comment: yes its working thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your two databases don't have the same collation. You need to specify the "COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT" clause in your join.

```
select * from db1.dbo.EPH e join db2.dbo.SALARIE s on e.id COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT=s.id COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft SQL Server, the collation can be set at the column level. When you compare (or concatenate) two columns having different collation in a query.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM db1.dbo.EPH e
JOIN db2.dbo.SALARIE s
ON e.id COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = s.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS

```
select * 
from db1.dbo.EPH e 
join db2.dbo.SALARIE s on
e.id COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = s.id
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```